# Not getting anything in RPC Call from JS in Odoo11

Tags: javascript, python, linux, odoo, odoo-11

I'm trying to make an RPC call to a method in python, but in the form view nothings happens

```
odoo.define('alicuam.show_modal_on_load', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    console.log("js loaded");
    var FormController = require('web.FormController');
    var Dialog = require('web.Dialog');

    FormController.include({
        events: _.extend({}, FormController.prototype.events, {
            'click .preview_btn': '_onPreviewBtnClick',
        }),

        _onPreviewBtnClick: function () {
            var self = this; // Guardar el contexto
            this._rpc({
                model: 'crm.files',
                method: 'open_file_preview_dialog',
            }).then(function (result) {
                if (result && result.html_content !== null) { // Revisar resultado
                    var dialog = new Dialog(self, {  // Usar el contexto guardado
                        title: 'Preview',
                        size: 'large',
                        $content: $(result.html_content)
                    });
                    dialog.open();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('.modal-backdrop').addClass('fade_out');
                        $('.o_act_window').parents('.o_technical_modal').first().addClass('slide_up');
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                            $('.o_act_window').parents('.o_technical_modal').first().remove();
                        }, 350);
                        let $targetModal = dialog.$el.parents('.o_technical_modal').first();
                        $targetModal.addClass("dialog_preview");
                        console.log("Added class to: ", $targetModal.length, " elements");
                        $('.dialog_preview').css('z-index', 9999);
                        console.log("Z-index applied");
                    }, 50);
                } else {
                    console.log("Resultado es null o undefined");
                }
            }).catch(function (error) {  // Manejar errores
                console.error("Error en la solicitud RPC:", error);
            });
        },
    });
});
```

The Js code above it is supposed to call and get the result of this method but somehow doesn't, what am I doing wrong?

```
    def open_file_preview_dialog(self):
        _logger.info('El método open_file_preview_dialog ha sido llamado.')
        if self.uri:
            uri_split = self.uri.split('.')
            file_format = uri_split[-1]

            # Verificar las dos últimas extensiones
            last_two_ext = uri_split[-2:]

            # Si la última extensión es 'jpeg' y la penúltima es una extensión problemática
            if last_two_ext[-1].lower() == 'jpeg' and last_two_ext[-2].lower() in ['gif', 'webp', 'tif', 'tiff']:
                file_format = last_two_ext[-2]

            response = requests.get(self.uri)
        else:
            return

        if response.ok:
            file_content = response.content
            file_data = base64.decodebytes(file_content)

            # PROCESSING IMAGES
            # if file_format in ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'webp', 'tiff']:
            #     content_type = 'image'
            #     img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(file_data))
            #     img_temp = io.BytesIO()
            #     img.save(img_temp, format=f'{file_format.upper()}')
            #     file = img_temp
            #     tag = 'img'
            #
            #     content = f'<{tag} src="data:{content_type};base64,{base64.b64encode(file.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")}" style="border: 0; width: {img.size[0]}px; height: {img.size[1]}px;" />'
            #     html_content = f'''
            #             <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 100vh;">
            #                 {content}
            #             </div>'''

            if file_format in ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'webp', 'tiff', 'tif']:
                mime_types = {
                    'png': 'image/png',
                    'jpg': 'image/jpeg',
                    'jpeg': 'image/jpeg',
                    'webp': 'image/jpeg',
                    'tiff': 'image/tiff',
                    'tif': 'image/tif'
                }

                try:
                    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(file_data))

                    if file_format == 'webp':
                        img = img.convert("RGB")
                        file_format = 'jpg'

                    img_temp = io.BytesIO()
                    img.save(img_temp, format=f'{file_format.upper()}')
                except Exception:
                    try:
                        # Intentar con imageio
                        if file_format == 'tiff' or file_format == 'tif':
                            img_array = imageio.imread(io.BytesIO(file_data), format='tifffile')
                        elif file_format == 'webp':
                            img_array = imageio.imread(io.BytesIO(file_data))

                        img_temp = io.BytesIO()
                        imageio.imsave(img_temp, img_array, format='JPEG')
                        file_format = 'jpeg'
                    except Exception:
                        # Intentar con OpenCV
                        img_array = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(file_data, np.uint8), -1)

                        # Convertir a RGB si es necesario
                        if len(img_array.shape) == 3 and img_array.shape[2] == 4:
                            img_array = cv2.cvtColor(img_array, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)

                        _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img_array)
                        img_temp = io.BytesIO(buffer)
                        file_format = 'jpeg'

                file = img_temp
                content_type = mime_types.get(file_format, 'image')
                tag = 'img'

                content = f'<{tag} src="data:{content_type};base64,{base64.b64encode(file.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")}" style="border: 0; width: {img.size[0] if "img_array" not in locals() else img_array.shape[1]}px; height: {img.size[1] if "img_array" not in locals() else img_array.shape[0]}px;" />'
                html_content = f'''
                        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 100vh;">
                            {content}
                        </div>'''

            # PROCESSING PDFs
            elif file_format == 'pdf':
                content_type = 'application/pdf'
                pdf_temp = io.BytesIO(file_data)
                file = pdf_temp
                tag = 'iframe'

                html_content = f'<{tag} src="data:{content_type};base64,{base64.b64encode(file.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")}" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100vh; allowfullscreen" />'

            # PROCESSING XMLs
            elif file_format == 'xml':
                xml_content = file_data.decode('utf-8')
                formatted_xml = html.escape(xml_content)
                html_content = f'<pre>{formatted_xml}</pre>'

            else:
                raise Warning(f"Lo sentimos el formato {file_format} no esta actualmente soportado para previsualizacion")

        # return {
        #     'name': 'Eventos',
        #     'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        #     'res_model': 'crm.lead',
        #     'res_id': self.lead_id.id,
        #     'view_mode': 'form',
        #     'view_type': 'form',
        #     'context': { 'file_preview': html_content },  # si necesitas pasar información adicional
        #     'target': 'new',  # si deseas que se abra en la forma de modal
        # }
        _logger.info(f'Esto voy a retornar: {html_content}')
        return {'html_content': html_content }
```

Please help me when i call the JS code in my Network application im getting the result ok but nothing happens in the view it is supposed to show it in the Dialog

```
{jsonrpc: "2.0", id: 905282351, result: {,…}}
id
: 
905282351
jsonrpc
: 
"2.0"
result
: 
{,…}
flags
: 
{}
html_content
: 
"<pre>&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;\r\n&lt;cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi=&quot;h....;</pre>"
type
: 
"ir.actions.act_window_close"
```

Comment: Could u please provide the results of your console.log and _logger.info ?

Comment: Have you tried the debug modus to put break-points in your js and/or in python codes ?